# IndexError: Target 5 is out of bounds

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning, neural-network, kaggle

I'm trying to train an ANN but get

> IndexError: Target 5 is out of bounds

I believe the problem is in this part of my code where I split the data:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
california = fetch_california_housing()
data = pd.DataFrame(california.data)
data.columns = california.feature_names
data['Price'] = california.target

X = data.iloc[:, 0:8]
y = data.iloc[:, 8]
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?
Here is the error:

```
    IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    Input In [174], in <cell line: 58>()
         55     plt.title("California House Prices Training Loss")
         56     plt.show()
    ---> 58 train(classifier, optimizer, epochs, loss_fn)
    
    Input In [174], in train(classifier, optimizer, epochs, loss_fn)
         43 for epoch in range(epochs):
         44     out = classifier(X_train)
    ---> 45     loss = loss_fn(out, y_train)
         46     loss.backward()
         47     optimizer.step()
    
    File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1194, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
       1190 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
       1191 # this function, and just call forward.
       1192 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
       1193         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
    -> 1194     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
       1195 # Do not call functions when jit is used
       1196 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []
    
    File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py:1174, in CrossEntropyLoss.forward(self, input, target)
       1173 def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    -> 1174     return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
       1175                            ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction,
       1176                            label_smoothing=self.label_smoothing)
    
    File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:3026, in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
       3024 if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
       3025     reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
    -> 3026 return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
    
    IndexError: Target 5 is out of bounds.
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the whole error traceback message.

Comment: I have added the error, would you be able to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Adding new columns then selecting by column index is error-prone.

In `scikit-learn>=0.23.0`, `fetch_california_housing` can already return a dataframe with the `as_frame` parameter.

If you need dataframes, your code should be structured like this:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing

california = fetch_california_housing(as_frame=True)

X = california.data
y = california.target
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it hasn't worked. I uploaded my file to GitHub: https://github.com/GeorgeCGarman/california-ann

Comment: Please take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which states: "*also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.*" If you copy the full error message into the question and can frame this as a minimal reproducible example, I might be better able to help you.

Comment: Hello, I have posted the error, would you be able to help?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing

# dataframe
df = fetch_california_housing(as_frame=True).frame

dataset = fetch_california_housing()
X, y = dataset.data, dataset.target
features = dataset.feature_names
features

['MedInc',
 'HouseAge',
 'AveRooms',
 'AveBedrms',
 'Population',
 'AveOccup',
 'Latitude',
 'Longitude']
```